# date difference calculation

Tags: javascript, web-part

I want to calculate difference between two date columns in html table inside SharePoint web part using JavaScript.

example

```
project    start       end          duration
------------------------------------------
Project 1  05/05/2017  10/05/2017   5 days
Project 1  04/05/2017  10/05/2017   6 days
```

EDIT: how to loop on each row to calculate the duration !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to achieve this,
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>`

`*****Javascript*****`

```
  var date1 = new Date('05/05/2017');
  var date2 = new Date('05/10/2017');
  var firstDate = moment(date1);
  var secondDate = moment(date2);

  var days = Math.abs(firstDate.diff(secondDate,'days'));
  alert(days+" days");
```

Comment: thank you . how to  loop on the html table to get the value of start date and end date from table cell

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3248951/5529407

Answer (score 4):

You can use below syntax it is working in our solution

`var startDate = new Date(strSDate);
var endDate = new Date(strEDate);
var days = ((endDate - startDate)/1000/60/60/24);`

Comment: thank you . how to  loop on the html table to get the value of start date and end date from table cell