# How to count number of days from SharePoint list?

Tags: javascript, calculated-column, caml, calculated-column-formula, query

How to count number of days between two dates from SharePoint list using CAML query/JavaScript?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get it using calculated column in SharePoint list. Try using below formula:

```
=DATEDIF([Column1], [Column2],"d")
```

**Reference**: [Calculate the difference between two dates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates)

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response. sorry for not providing enough info. I would like to count using CAML query/ JavaScript. the formula you provided is working for single time.

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve.

- If you want to get the number of days between two dates using JavaScript then below script can be used

  ```
  var date1 = new Date("06/30/2019"); 

  var date2 = new Date("07/30/2019");

  var Difference_In_Time = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime(); 

  var Difference_In_Days = Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
  ```
- If you want to use date range in CAML query and need to return items within date range then use Offset days in your CAML query

[Using Date Range in CAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31873761/caml-query-filtering-data-within-a-date-range)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.
I did as yours but mine is a bit different it takes date database and subtracting from current date which is date2 and it returns NaN:
function diffDays(date){
var date1 = new Date(date); 

var date2 = new Date();

var Difference_In_Time = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime(); 

var Difference_In_Days = Difference_In_Time / (1000 * 3600 * 24);
}

Comment: Can you send me the dates you are using

Comment: well date is taken from database like 30/3/2020 and subtracting from current date using new Date().

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript, then consider using **moment.js**.
Then format the date using moment.js. In your case you can use like this,

```
moment(moment('30/3/2020', 'DD/MM/YYYY')).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

For no.of days count check this [answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/214643/58747).